Drizzle ORM: how to add data to two tables with many-to-many relations
I want to insert data according to the following codes to the two tables named as productTable and discountCodeTable in the following way. These two tables have a many to many relationship and are connected to each other through a join-table called productToDiscount.
I have the same syntax to import these changes through prisma, but I want to convert it to drizzle.
**create data by prisma
await db.discountCode.create({
    data: {
      code: data.code,
      discountAmount: data.discountAmount,
      discountType: data.discountType,
      allProducts: data.allProducts,
      products:
        data.productIds != null
          ? { connect: data.productIds.map((id) => ({ id })) }
          : undefined,
      expiredAt: data.expiredAt,
      limit: data.limit,
    },
  });

data that I want to insert
const addSchema = z
  .object({
    code: z.string().min(1),
    discountAmount: z.coerce.number().int().min(1),
    discountType: z.nativeEnum(DiscountCodeType),
    allProducts: z.coerce.boolean(),
    productIds: z.array(z.string()).optional(),
    expiredAt: z.preprocess(
      (value) => (value === '' ? undefined : value),
      z.coerce.date().min(new Date()).optional()
    ),
    limit: z.preprocess(
      (value) => (value === '' ? undefined : value),
      z.coerce.number().int().min(1).optional()
    ),
  })

** product,discountCode and their join tables schema in drizzle:
export const ProductTable = pgTable('product', {
  id: uuid('id').primaryKey().defaultRandom(),
  name: varchar('name', { length: 70 }).notNull(),
  priceInCent: integer('priceInCent').notNull(),
  description: varchar('description', { length: 100 }).notNull(),
  filePath: varchar('filePath').notNull(),
  imagePath: varchar('imagePath').notNull(),
  isAvailableForPurchase: boolean('isAvailableForPurchase')
    .default(true)
    .notNull(),
  createdAt: timestamp('createdAt').notNull().defaultNow(),
  updatedAt: timestamp('updatedAt').notNull(),
  email: varchar('email', { length: 255 }).unique(),
});

export const DiscountCodeTable = pgTable('discountCode', {
  //choose every columns name and features:
  id: uuid('id').primaryKey().defaultRandom(),
  code: varchar('code').unique(),
  discountAmount: integer('discountAmount').notNull(),
  discountType: DiscountCodeType('discountCodeType').default('FIXED').notNull(),
  uses: integer('uses').default(0).notNull(),
  isActive: boolean('isActive').default(true).notNull(),
  allProducts: boolean('allProducts').default(false),
  createdAt: timestamp('createdAt').notNull().defaultNow(),
  expiredAt: timestamp('updatedAt'),
  limit: integer('limit'),
});

export const productToDiscountCode = pgTable(
  'productToDiscountCode',
  {
    productId: varchar('productId')
      .notNull()
      .references(() => ProductTable.id),
    discountCodeId: varchar('discountCodeId')
      .notNull()
      .references(() => DiscountCodeTable.id),
  },
  (t) => ({
    pk: primaryKey({ columns: [t.productId, t.discountCodeId] }),
  })
);

how to convert it to drizzle?
